# Showing that $gl_n$ is a sum of one-dimensional representations

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $h ⊆ gl_n$ be the set of diagonal matrices. Check that $h$ is a commutative Lie subalgebra. Check that $gl_n$ as the h-module (with respect to adjoint action) is a sum of one-dimensional representations.

First part:

To show that $h$ is a lie subalgebra, I think it is enough to show:
For all $H_1, H_2 \in h$ we have $[H_1,H_2] \in h$.
And that is true since we'll get the zero matrix when calculating $H_1*H_2-H_2*H_1$ and the zero matrix is indeed a diagonal matrix so $[H_1,H_2] \in h.

For the second part if $L$ is a lie algebra and $x\in L$ then we define an operator on $L$:

$a_x:L\to L$

By $ad_x(y)=[x,y]$.

In our case $L=gl_n$ and  $H\in hl_n$ so
$ad_H(G)=[H,G]$ , $(G\in gl_n)$.

I don't undersatand what they mean by the second part and how it can be shown. What does
I will appreciate any explanation or guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Let $E_{ij}\in\mathfrak{gl}_n$ be the matrix $(a_{kl})_{1\leqslant k,l\leqslant n}$ such that $a_{kl}=1$ when $(k,l)=(i,j)$ and that $a_{kl}=0$ otherwise. If $\Bbbk$ if the field over which you are working, then $\Bbbk E_{ij}$ is $1$-dimensional. And if$$H=\begin{bmatrix}h_1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&h_2&&\ldots&0\\0&0&h_3&\ldots&0\\&\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&h_n\end{bmatrix},$$then $H\in\mathfrak h$ and $[H,E_{ij}]=(h_i-h_j)E_{ij}$. Therefore, $\Bbbk E_{ij}$ is a $1$-dimensional $\mathfrak h$-module. And, cleraly,$$\mathfrak{gl}_n=\bigoplus_{i,j=1}^n\Bbbk E_{ij}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I have some question, maybe trivial ones. How does $a_kl$ look? (I am a little confused with its definition). Then why is  $kE_ij$ one dimensional? And an h-module? @José Carlos Santos

Comment: As a vector space, $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ has dimension $n^2$ with basis vectors $E_{ij}$. So $\Bbb k E_{ij}$ is obviously a $1$-dimensional subspace and has an action by $\mathfrak{h}$.

Comment: Why is $[H,E_{ij}]=(h_i-h_j)E_{ij}$ NOT 0? @Dietrich Burde

Comment: Just compute $[H,E_{ij}]$, as I did.